# S3.getSignedUrl upload corrupted video file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to upload video files bigger than 10 MB, so I sending to frontend link generate via s3.getSignedUrl. I can upload video file into S3, but it is corrupted (I can not play it). When I look in metadata info of uploaded video file I see the Content-Type is **multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------552383848847187991927004**

```
const s3: S3 = new S3({
  apiVersion: '2010-12-01',
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
  region: process.env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION || 'eu-west-1',
});
const params = {
      Bucket: mediaBucket,
      Key: 'videos/' + Constants.SUBSUBFOLDER.original + '/' + name,
      Expires: 1000,
      ContentType: 'video/mp4',
    };
    const s3Values = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params);
```

Bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::media.devel.acme.xxx.com/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:putObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::media.devel.acme.xxx.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you uploading the file via HTTP PUT or a form POST from a web browser? It looks like the latter (in which case see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html).

Comment: I try it via PUT from postman

Comment: This works fine for me when using curl to PUT an MPEG file to the pre-signed URL. The content-type is correct (video/mp4) if I include it explicitly in the PUT headers, and it's binary/octet-stream if I don't supply a content-type in the PUT. Here's how I used curl: `curl -X PUT -T sample.mp4 -H "Content-Type: video/mp4" <signed url>`. If I download the MPEG in either scenario, it's fine and plays normally.

Comment: I had binary/octet-stream content-type before when I uploading files via s3.upload, because I must to start uploading files from client-side, because I can upload more than 10MB files request into Amazon services. Now I have this multipart content-type. Now I try it with .jpg file and its damage too. I sending it like form-data multipart. Is it possible that problem is in it?

Comment: I was able to upload (and download) a 14MB file just fine using the same method. Try the curl PUT approach that I used and, if it works, try to understand what the difference is between that and your use of Postman.